# send data from a page to many other pages in a universal app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have this architecture in my universal Project:
[image]

the problem is that I can't send Data from the "SearchPage" to the "Detailslocal",I have correctly send the same Data from "MainPage" to "DetailsLocal" with the NaviatedTo() method,but I don't know how can I send the Data that "SearchPage" get from "MainPage" to "DetailsLocal"
any idea please
sorry for my question,I am new in the windows store apps
thanks for help

Comment: You can save data in LocalSettings of App and use it wherever you want. But data to be saved  in LocalSettings should be serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to doing this task i will suggest you the following ways to do it

1- Make appropriate properties in view controller where you need values and send your required values to next view controller from previous view controller.

2- Make Singleton class and make properties in that class then store your required values in appropriate properties to get those values anywhere in whole project.

Comment: thanks waaris shams for your reply,but I have question please,I heared that Microsoft Technologies use MVVM Model,is it possible to do this with MVVM model???

Comment: You can get help from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535572/mvvm-share-object-between-the-all-the-views

Answer (score 1):

You can save data in LocalSettings of App and use it wherever you want. But data to be saved in LocalSettings should be serializable

```
Var LocalSettings = Windows.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
```

Comment: thanks Archana I will try your solution :)